# Call a newcommand (or robust command) within \label

Tags: macros, labels, robust-commands

I would like to pass a newcommand to `\label`. Could you please help me how to do this?

My (uncompilable) MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ltlab}{lab}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{l}
\caption{This is a cool table.}
\label{table:{\ltlab}}
\end{longtable}

Table~\ref{table:{\ltlab}} contains nothing.

\end{document}
```

**Update:** @Phelype Oleinik reminded me that there was a typo in this MWE. After correcting this typo and using `\newcommand` instead of \DeclareRobustCommand, I received what I wanted to have.

Comment: I do not insist on using `\DeclareRobustCommand`, just to define a `\label` separately from what it points to (in the present case, to a `\longtable`).

Comment: Don't declare the command with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, use `\newcommand` instead.  Also, you have a typo in `\label{table:{\ltab}}`: it should be `\label{table:{\ltlab}}` (also the braces are unnecessary: you could write `\label{table:\ltlab}`).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'd say that braces should be avoided. They're not “wrong”, but they produce a funny label.

Comment: Thanks, I works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `\DeclareRobustCommand` when the command should survive full expansion that happens in `\write` operations. But the argument to `\label` and `\ref` needs quite the opposite: it should expand to a string of characters that's legal in the context of `\csname...\endcsname`.

Thus you should definitely use `\newcommand`, which does no such protection.

By the way, `\label{table:{\ltlab}}` is legal, but produces a funny label with braces having category code 12.

There's no need of adding those braces: `\label{table:\ltlab}` is cleaner, in my opinion.